# How to delete records in one table based on the values in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are two tables:

table1

```
cm_id   cost
1       6.52
2       16.52
3       2.12
4       7.14
5       19.09
6       11.52
7       0.12
```

table2

```
um_id   order_num   name
1       517         tommy
2       518         bobby
3       519         scotty
4       520         faris
5       521         justine
6       522         sadie
7       523         nicole
```

cm_id and um_id represent the same thing so the cost can be tied to each order number, ie

```
SELECT table1.cm_id, table1.cost, table2.order_num, table2.order_num
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.cm_id=table2.um_id;
```

What is the single SQL statement I can use to delete rows from table1 where the order_num in table2 is between 518 and 520?

Comment: I believe this should [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439750/t-sql-selecting-rows-to-delete-via-joins). Just use a join.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I've got a lot of learning to do!

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
delete 
from table1
where cm_id IN (select um_id from table2 where order_num between 518 and 520)
```

Comment: Why not? What would be efficient? Is there another way?

Answer (score 8):

```
DELETE table1
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.cm_id = table2.um_id
AND    (table2.order_num BETWEEN 518 AND 520)

--OR

DELETE 
FROM  table1
USING table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.cm_id = table2.um_id
WHERE   (table2.order_num BETWEEN 518 AND 520)
```

## EDIT:

There was a duplicate `FROM` and query has been changed as per `Andriy M` comments.

Comment: This would work in SQL Server. [In MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html "MySQL ::   MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 12.2.2 DELETE Syntax") you should either *a)* remove the first `FROM` or *b)* replace the second `FROM` with `USING`.

Comment: Also, how do these two queries differ from each other? (I mean, apart from the fact that the second one contains fewer spaces.)

Comment: Oh, I actually forgot to put WHERE clause to 2nd query, I'm changing accordingly, thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: when I was saying, *‘remove `FROM`… replace `FROM`…’*, I meant just the keywords themselves, not the entire *clauses*. Well, you can see the right syntax in the linked article.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, so should I edit again? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, I think you should, because the main issue, wrong syntax, is still there. I've already given you the article on the right syntax and I even suggested (in plain words) what particular changes you should make to your queries. You only need to apply the changes. :)

Comment: @AndriyM, I've changed accordingly, would you please have a look over the changes, thank your for your valuable time.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer this way

```
delete from table1
using table1, table2
where table1.cm_id = table2.um_id
and table2.order_num >= 518
and table2.order_num <= 520;
```

Answer (score 2):

use DELETE with subquery:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.cm_id IN (SELECT table2.um_id FROM table2 WHERE order_num>=518 and order_num<=520)
```

Comment: DELETE FROM  not DELETE * FROM

Answer (score 1):

As `IN` has some performance limitations we can use delete command with simple join query like

```
delete x from table1 x,table2 y where x.cm_id=y.um_id;
```