# Unable to delete rows based on key in another table

Tags: mysql

This is working:

```
select *  FROM Work_Request A where EXISTS  ( select 1  from Customer B where (B.lsource&128)!=0 and B.license_id=A.license_id) ;
```

As per [Delete all rows in a table based on another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table) this delete should also work but instead giving error:

```
delete  FROM Work_Request A where EXISTS  ( select 1  from Customer B where (B.lsource&128)!=0 and B.license_id=A.license_id) ;
```

**Error:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'A where EXISTS ..

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your delete statement should be like this

```
delete  A.* FROM Work_Request A 
where EXISTS  ( select 1  from Customer B where (B.lsource&128)!=0 and B.license_id=A.license_id) ;
```

you are missing name of table thats gonna delete ...have fun :-)