# SQL command: deleting rows based on condition in another table

Tags: sql

I am looking for the SQL command to delete rows of data from one table based on a condition in another table. Basically I'd like to delete all row data from table 1 where a userid in table 1 = a userid in table 2.

Comment: which db you are using  ..

Comment: Delete from ....  join ...  where schould work

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I completly understand your question
is this what you are asking for?

```
  DELETE Table1
   FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table)!

Comment: In my SQL system, delete is disabled. Any ideas on workarounds not using delete? I tried a LEFT JOIN where table2.userid is not null but didn't work correctly.

Comment: Never heard of disabled delete. Can you please share your code..or check the condition that you are setting. It must have to do something with that

Comment: it's the in-house tool that disables the delete function, no setting I can change.

Comment: Tried `TRUNCATE` ?

Comment: Please hit the Up button if I was helpful. Peace

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use following query, regardless of the SQL engine:

```
delete from table1 
where exists (select * from table2 where table2.userid = table1.userid)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was unable to resolve it using the where exists clause. For my use case that deleted all the rows in my table so beware of it, I was thankfully using a duplicate table to test this.

I had a table with duplicate values but only wanted to keep the most recent ones (had a column with the date for this). To solve my issue and to simplify my query I stored the table with the rows I wanted to delete, in a view and used that view to be the source of the rows to be deleted from the table in question.

It's essentially an adaptation from what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1590825/14756032) but I'll add some comments so it becomes clearer.

```
DELETE Table1
FROM Table1 T
INNER JOIN View1 V ON T.id = V.id 
and T.year = V.year 
and T.measure_id = V.measure_id 
and T.[date_added] != V.[date_added]
```

Table1 - the table you want to change both after delete and from
View 1 - a view I created that contained the exact lines I wanted to delete

As you can see my example was a bit more complex (by having to use all the keys for common lines) but using a view made it simpler (maybe an idea for anyone else out there with a similar issue).