# How to find duplicate rows in different table

Tags: mysql

**My Problem:** I have got two MySQL tables. One table is called *txns* and another table is called *archived_txns*. Both of the tables has same columns. I use **archived_txns** to move data from **txns** using a PHP script.

**I want to know how can I find out and delete the *duplicate rows* within these two tables.** I am adding the Table structure for better reference.

> This is the **archived_txns** table

[image]

> This is the **txns** table

[image]

As stated in this example, I want to find out and delete the row with **ID 3** from the **txns** table.

Comment: Please define "duplicate rows". Which column values must be equal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590799/delete-all-rows-in-a-table-based-on-another-table

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The Column Values for "id" must be equal in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete it using `JOIN`

```
DELETE t 
FROM txns t
JOIN archived_txns a ON t.id = a.id
```